# Bootstrap remove opacity for alert

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap modal for a simple login form:

```
<div class="modal fade login">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body row">        
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Login panel</h4>
                </div>
                <form class="capture" method="post" name="login">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="form-group btn btn-default btn-block">Login</button>
                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer"><center><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></center></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am also using jQuery to handle the login and returning a callback which I would like to show as an alert box using boostrap.

This is working fine, however the alert message is affected by the modal opacity and difficult to see.

How can I make the alert message box appear without being affected by the modal opacity?

I tried the following CSS:

```
.notification{
    position: fixed;
    top: 3em;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity:0;
}
```

The div is as follows

```
<div id="notification"></div>
```

Controlled by the following jquery, which is triggered from inside a modal:

```
function flash(type,message){
        $(".notification").remove();
        $("#notification").append($("<div class='notification alert alert-" + type + " fade in' data-alert><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a><b>"+type.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+type.slice(1)+"</b>: "+message+"</div>"));
        $(".notification").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow", function () { $(this).remove(); });
    }
```

However, the message box is still hindered by the opacity.

Comment: can you show a working example? I'm not sure how your alert-box looks like and where it's placed.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the `.notification` element in your HTML. However from the description it sounds like it is the child of an element with its' opacity set, in which case you would need to remove it from this parent.

Comment: Updated with missing code samples.

Comment: It's not clear to me what "alert message box" you are talking about

Comment: If from inside the modal I call the `flash` function the alert box (bootstrap) is behind the modal opacity - but I want it to be in front.

Comment: Anyone else with this issue, you can move the div where the pop-up appears outside the container, then it isn't affected by the opacity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make the z-index slightly larger. If you inspect the style for `.modal` you'll notice it has a `z-index` of 1050. You'll need to set your `z-index` equal to or larger than this value.

```
.notification{
    position: fixed;
    top: 3em;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    z-index: 1051; /* must be equal to or larger than .modal */
    opacity:0;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gzans41/1/) for reference. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bart, I tried updating the z-index, but the alert box is still affected by the modal opacity background. I want the alert box to be in-front of the darkened opacity on the main page.

Comment: @user1220022 ah yes you're right. Looks like the `z-index` value is actually 1050 when I inspect in console. It works if you set it to 1051. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gzans41/) for reference.

Comment: **UPDATE 2017:** Bootstrap 4 has a nice writeup in the docs which goes over [how they set z-index](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#z-index)